# Core Data performBlockAndWait no autorelease poll

Tags: ios, core-data

In the WWDC 2012 video of core data best practices, the guy states that performBlockAndWait: doesn't contain an autorelease pool. (whereas performBlock: does)

Why not? What exactly are the consequences of this? Do I need to wrap the block contents in an autorelease pool - all the apple examples don't do this. Or was his point to contrast performBlock: and this doesn't need one.

Comment: Would be good if down voters were forced to say why they down voted - constructive criticism !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

bandejapaisa,

A -performBlockAndWait: benefits from the surrounding autorelease pool. (-performBlockAndWait: appears to execute directly on the current thread.) Hence, it doesn't need its own autorelease pool.

Andrew

Comment: Cool, that's what I suspected. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

`performBlockAndWait:` is reentrant. It does not provide an autorelease pool, or processing of user events (it does not call `processPendingChanges`), and executes on a thread managed  by the context's queue.

Because it is reentrant, it blocks the calling thread until completion. This behavior is not compatible with both autorelease pools and Core Data user events, which is why it does not use them (while `performBlock:`) does.